# PHP compare time

Tags: php, date, time

How to compare times in PHP?

I want to say this:

```
$ThatTime ="14:08:10";
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');
$time_now=mktime(date('G'),date('i'),date('s'));
$NowisTime=date('G:i:s',$time_now);
if($NowisTime >= $ThatTime) {
    echo "ok";
}
```

The above code does not print ok.  I expected it to.

Comment: What are are trying to accomplish?

Comment: All the answers assume both times are within the same day. Depending on your application, that may be okay. Others may have times from different days in which case you can get the wrong answer unless you change the code to consider dates as well.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
$ThatTime ="14:08:10";
if (time() >= strtotime($ThatTime)) {
  echo "ok";
}
```

A solution using `DateTime` (that also regards the timezone).

```
$dateTime = new DateTime($ThatTime);
if ($dateTime->diff(new DateTime)->format('%R') == '+') {
  echo "OK";
}
```

http://php.net/datetime.diff

Comment: ok but time() will take the time of the server? -BEcause I need to specify the default timezone each time by date_default_timezone_set($TimeZone);

Comment: @DiegoP.: Must say, I didn't realized it before, but you're right. However, Ive added another solution using `DateTime`.

Comment: It gives an error =(( Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()

Comment: Oh no I can not ask to all my customers to use the 5.3 version..I need a smarter solution..Why it is soo difficult. It is driving me crazy! Do not you have another solution? Thank you so much

Comment: Just realize: `strtotime()` regard the timezone too, so the first example should work just fine. http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: In the case of PHP 5.2 or lower I'd suggest numerically comparing UNIX timestamps. They're numbers after all.

Comment: @techouse You shouldn't use 5.2 or lower. I suggest to update as soon as possible.

Comment: For performance choice, `strtotime` is better than `DateTime`. https://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/19/benchmark-strtotime-vs-datetime-vs-gettimestamp-in-php/

Comment: @NickTsai: a) The benchmark is from 2013. You should rerun it. b) The author doesn't provide the full benchmark script, which makes it hard to reproduce. c) He measured with 100.000 iterations. This will hardly happen in reality. The absolute difference for 100 iterations is 1ms. Which leads to --> d) Choose the solution, that better fit your needs/architecture. Saving 1ms overall is micro optimization.

Comment: @NickTsai One last thing: I'd rerun the benchmark with PHP7.2 and the result is even more "it doesnt matter" (because of 0,1ms difference for more realistic 100 conversion). https://gist.github.com/KingCrunch/8c9c3a39ccc4eb9a8623550ab0c3b62d I've added the "datetime without instanciation" test, because in a clean architecture you often already has the instance, so it would effect all variants and therefore should be kept out.

Comment: @KingCrunch Nice job! I'd like your benchmark test. Thanks. BTW, for me, I would choose `strtotime()` only if I don't need the `DateTime` features.

Answer (score 15):

To see of the curent time is greater or equal to 14:08:10 do this:

```
if (time() >= strtotime("14:08:10")) {
  echo "ok";
}
```

Depending on your input sources, make sure to account for timezone.

See [PHP time()](http://php.net/time)
and [PHP strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime)

Answer (score 12):

Simple way to compare time is :

```
$time = date('H:i:s',strtotime("11 PM"));
if($time < date('H:i:s')){
     // your code
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad solution, but it is a string comparison, not a proper date comparison. The most precise and, at the same time, simple way to compare dates and times is to turn them into unix timestamps using strtotime() function.