# Compare current time with 00:00:00 in php

Tags: php, time

I want to perform something in my php web service when it is midnight i.e. current time is 24:00:00 / 00:00:00

How can I do that ?

Comment: [PHP compare time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time).

Comment: do you need background thread to do this or you want to check this when the webservice is in use in midnight  ??

Comment: my web service is already running infinitely only at midnight some specific task needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [localtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php) in order to fetch current time of day, and then work on that using an if statement.

Eg.

```
$localtime = localtime();
if ($localtime[2] == 0) {
    code;
}
```

Keep in mind that this only works on script that is continually executed (eg. index.php), if you want a script to execute regardless of whether it's currently being executed at the desired time, you need to use chron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled task which runs at a certain time and runs your script as:

```
php -f o/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP [Cron Jobs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) with cPanel

cPanel Simple Cron

you can get started with the simple cron tool built into cPanel.

1)Go to Cpanel

2)click cron job tab

3)Set time and page url for it is: https://www.yoursite.com/page.php

The command to run:

```
  /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/(username)/public_html/page.php
```