# Set div width and padding based on time duration

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am currently trying to figure out how could I set a DIV's dimensions based on a time duration. I am using the divs to represent events on a  calendar.  And have a from - to timestamp available for my events. I really can't seem to figure out what the best approach for this should be.

Let me give an example of what I am trying to do.

```
        <td style="position:relative;">
            <!-- Inspecting every event -->
                <?php foreach ($room['events'] as $event): ?>

                    <!-- generate event divs -->
                    <?php if(date('j', strtotime($event['e_from'])) == $x+1): ?>
                        <div    class="event"
                                style="
                                    width: 100px;
                                    margin-left: 30px;
                         ">
                             <!-- pupulate divs with content -->
                             blah blah blah

                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </td>
```

This code works. Now I need to replace the width and padding based on the time duration. I can access the timestamp using `$event['e_from']` and `$event['e_to']`. The strings look like this `2014-03-05 06:28:00`.

What I want to do it to set the padding based on the time in the event. For example if it starts at midnight padding is 0, if it starts at 1pm padding is 13px, etc. Basically 1px of padding for every hour. And then set the width based on the time between `e_from` and `e_to` also 1px for every hour. I am not 100% sure on the scale, but the logic will be the same anyway..

I guess I can't ask for the actual solution, therefore I will appreciate any tips or suggestions on how to approach this task. Thank you all for reading an in advance for your replies.

Comment: There are functions in PHP that can compare time, so that you don't have to write your own function (after all comparing time isn't comparing numbers). You can get it to output an integer difference of hours, after which it should be smooth sailing. Good luck!
EDIT: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/6158762/706798

Comment: and how should I make it so it increases by 1px each hour? Using a for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Would setting the padding to the result (the time difference represented as integer of hours) not work?

Comment: yeah it will work. I will use that for the width. But I still have to set the starting point of the div relative to the table cell. I want to do that by the padding. So I need some function that takes the time in the `e_from` and based on it sets the padding to appropriate value..

Comment: Ok. Then you need to loop through all your `e_from` values, and find the minimal one. Then that minimal value will correspond to your 0px padding, and all other padding will be calculated based on differenec from that original one

Comment: not entirely correct, but the approach is perfect. I will just find the time difference between "00:00:00" and the from timestamp and set the padding based on the difference and then the width based on the difference between from and to. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$maxWidth = 200; // px
$eventStart = strtotime('2014-03-01 20:54:00');
$eventEnd   = strtotime('2014-03-01 22:31:59');
$eventLength = $eventEnd - $eventStart;
$maxLength = 86400;
$ratio = $eventLength / $maxLength;

$width = round($ratio * $maxWidth);
```

You can set the scale from 0 to $maxWidth. In this case the width will be 13px.