# central time check php

Tags: php, time, timezone

I am trying to execute a code in PHP between midnight and 08:00 am at Central time.

I may have not explained correctly:

I have a form submission, I want to check when the user submit the form, if it within a time interval I want to do an additional action

How can I get the time on Central Standard Time?

How can I check it against specific interval?

Comment: `crontab -e` `google.com/#q=cron` || `man cron` || `man crontab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very specific, so I'm going to answer to what I *think* you're asking, however there are many ways to go about doing this.

---

> How can I get the time on Central Standard Time?

Using PHP's [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
```

[Here's the list of supported timezone strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

---

> How can I check it against specific interval?

Use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). To get started with `cron`, there's [a nice tutorial provided by TheGeekStuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/). In short, execute the following on your web server:

```
$> crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

---

**Edit** Persuant to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684879/central-time-check-php/24685002?noredirect=1#comment38275351_24685002), you just want to check what time the script is executing. You can use PHP's [`time()`](http://php.net/date) in combination with [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago"); // if your server isn't in/set to this timezone already, you're going to need this for proper comparison
if (strtotime("00:00:00") <= time() && time() <= strtotime("8:00:00")) {
    // if the time of the script's execution is between midnight and 8am, do something special
} else {
    // send to the normal e-mail, it's outside that specific window
}
```

<sub>[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158762/269970) made this one possible.</sub>

Comment: I have a submission form, if user submits on specif time interval I want to send to specif email. I am not looking to execute script automatically at specif time