# Create a function checking the day and time and return open or closed php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Hi I'm trying to create a function in php that checks the current day and business hours of that day and return if the store is open or closed. This is what I have so far, but it always comes back as closed.

```
$day = date( 'l' );
function get_biz_hours_openclosed( $hours_openclosed ) {
$day = 'Thursday';
$t = date("H:i a");
$d = date('l');
$dowstart = '9:00 am';
$dowend = '21:00 pm';
$openclosed = ''; //default return string to empty string
echo $hours_openclosed;
    if ( ($day == $d ) && ($dowstart < $t) && ($t < $dowend) ) {
        $openclosed = 'Open!';
    }
    else{ 
        $openclosed = 'Closed'; 
    }
return $openclosed; 
}

echo get_biz_hours_openclosed( $day );
echo "<br>";
echo "current time: " . date("H:i a");
```

Comment: `21:00 pm` ? you need to go back to your drawing board and learn how to compare variables because what you are doing currently is way way off

Comment: $dowstart and $dowend will be held in a variable within the WP theme.. so just for testing I'm trying to use hours how they would be printed out to see if it works correctly.

Comment: 9.00 am and 9.00 pm maybe

Comment: I'm still a newb with php so any tips or advice would be more helpful than telling me I'm way off.. this is one reason I asked the question

Comment: Riccardo - I've tried that as well and changed the time output so it outputs that same way.. still says closed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP compare time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
$day = date( 'l' );

function get_biz_hours_openclosed( $hours_openclosed ) {

$day = 'Friday'; // testing day of the week to see if it compares correctly
$d = date('l'); // current day 
$dowstart = '9:00 am'; // testing with an example open hour
$dowend = '9:00 pm'; // testing with an example close hour
$openclosed = ''; // default return string to empty string
echo $hours_openclosed;

if ( $day == $d && time() > strtotime($dowstart) && time() < strtotime($dowend) ) {
    $openclosed = "Open!";
} else { 
    $openclosed = "Closed"; 
}

return "<span>&nbsp;</span>" . $openclosed; 

}

echo get_biz_hours_openclosed( $day );
echo "<br>";
echo "current time: " . date("g:i a");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( ($day == $d )){ 

  if($t == '12:00pm'){
           $openclosed = 'Open!';
        }
  if($t <$dowend ) {
       $openclosed = 'Open!';
   }

  if(($t <'12:00pm') && ($t >='9:00am')){
        $openclosed = 'Open!';
           }

}
else{ 
    $openclosed = 'Closed'; 
}
```

not sure with the syntax (Not familiar with php)

Comment: that works how it is, but not sure how to implement it into my existing function.. I tried but it always says open now. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

From a delivery system project I made, I'm sure you can find what you want with this function :

```
function is_between_hours($h1 = array(), $h2 = array()){
    $est_hour = date('H');
    $h1 = ($h1[1] == 'am') ? $h1[0] : $h1[0]+12;
    $h1 = ($h1 === 24) ? 12 : $h1;
    $h2 = ($h2[1] == 'am') ? $h2[0] : $h2[0]+12;
    $h2 = ($h2 === 24) ? 12 : $h2;        
    echo "Current time:";
    echo $est_hour;
    echo "Opening time:";
    echo $h1;
    echo "Close time:";
    echo $h2;
    if ( $est_hour >= $h1 && $est_hour < $h2 ) {
        echo "store open";}
        else {
            echo "store close";}}
```