# How to check if gmdate later or earlier than time()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following script:

```
$zTime = gmdate("H:i",$min);
```

In the `mysqli` table (let's call it `events`) I have a column of `time` (not `datetime`!) type called `startTime`.

The question is, how can I check if the `$zTime` variable is earlier/later than `startTime` with `php`?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just use your comparison in your query, it can understand it by using a where clause

Comment: @Ghost for a specific reason I cannot use it inside the query, isn't it possible to check it with php?

Comment: its still possible in PHP, much better to have the comparison on the DB layer though, in PHP, either use `DateTime` classes to convert both to unix timestamp

Comment: @Ghost can you give me an example how the code should look like, please? Please be aware of the fact that $zTime variable should stay untouched (by using gmdate function)

Comment: create your query, fetch the results, then compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time

Comment: @Ghost, I have tried to use the comparison but it doesn't work, everytime it says that $zTime is later than "startTime" even if it is not.

Comment: Ok, I made an obvious mistake, your solution worked. Thank you very much, @Ghost!