# How would I compare specific time to the current time in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and would like to compare a specific time with the current time. I have tried different tricks but nothing works for me.
 Eg.

```
$my_time = '2:00';
$active='';

//echo "The time is " . date("h:ia");die;
if (date('h:i') > date('h:i', strtotime($myTime))) {
    $active='Dinner';
    $dinner=1;
}
else
{
    $active='Lunch';
    $lunch=1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP compare time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time)

Answer (score 0):

You have variable definition

```
$my_time = '2:00'
```

but you're using

```
strtotime($myTime))
```

Comment: :) Acually Maciej__ i get all this stuff while searching, am new in php. In  learning phase . if you know it pleasae guide me how to do that in proper way

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
$my_time ="14:08:10";
if (time() >= strtotime($my_time)) {
  echo "Dinner";
}else echo "Lunch";
```

This will compare given time with current time

Answer (score 0):

try this one .

```
$my_time ="14:08:10";
if (time() >= strtotime($my_time))
{
  echo "Dinner";
}
else
{
 echo "Lunch";
}
```

if this doesnt work try to add date in to time. 
because adding date will make time to be more specific.