# I want the result of the array php to be replaced with the current time

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array containing time and price and time, I want to check which time array the price will correspond :

```
 $myArray = array('8:00am'=>'200usd', '13:00pm'=>'300usd');
 $timecurrent = date("H:ia");
```

I want the result: time 8:00am -> 12:59pm set price 200usd

Comment: How is this mysql related?

Comment: sorry, my fault

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158762/5962966

Comment: @Milind Singh Thank you , But not true >.<

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution

```
$myArray = array('8:00am'=>'200usd', '9:00am'=>'250usd', '13:00pm'=>'300usd');
//Get current time
$timecurrent = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia', date('H:ia'));
$price = null;
$actualPrice = null;
foreach($myArray as $time=>$fee){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:ia', $time);
    if($timecurrent<$date){ //if crossed current time
        $actualPrice = $price; //Get previous element time and stop
        break;
    }
    //Save fee for next iteration
    $price = $fee;
}

echo $actualPrice; //250usd
```

Comment: Thank! I have adjusted