# How to use PHP If statement comparing to SQL Date and Current Date?

Tags: php, mysql

In my SQL Database i have a date column.
I want to use a PHP if statement to show some text if the date from the DB equals todays date.
Aswell as that, use an else to show something else if the date does not equal today.

Running PHP 7

I have lost count of what i have tried with this but don't seem to get anywhere.

I am fetching the data here:

```
    $sql1 = 'SELECT `date` FROM `operations`.`opsroom` ORDER BY `opsroom`.`date` ASC, `opsroom`.`starttime` ASC LIMIT 1';
    $nextsession = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
```

Later on in the file is where i am using this:

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nextsession)) 
    {
    if( $row['date'] == DATE(date)){
    echo "BOOKINGS TODAY";
    } else {
    echo "No Bookings";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Only error i get at the moment is PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant date - assumed 'date' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: it's `date` not `DATE` - this is why lowercase is much better practice.

Comment: `DATE(date)` calls the function [`date`](http://php.net/date) (case is ignored for function names), with `"date"` (converted from bare constant `date`, hence the warning) as the format string, which is nonsense. For starters, what is the exact value of `$row['date']`…?

Comment: `DATE(date)` - what date do you want to compare to?

Comment: If you're trying to compare the date from the DB to **today's** date, you probably just need `$row['date'] == date('Y-m-d')` ...

Comment: Would probably be easier and cleaner to modify your query to only retrieve data that matches the date. Why get any more data than you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper `date` function of PHP:

If you want to compare today date then try below:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nextsession)) 
{
 // this one you need to change
 if( $row['date'] == date('Y-m-d')){
    echo "BOOKINGS TODAY";
 } else {
    echo "No Bookings";
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked thanks!
Do you know how i can do something similar for date and time.
within the $nextsession there is date, starttime endtime columns.
So i need to work out how to get it to show something if date is today and startttime is greater than current time and less than endtime?

Comment: @StevenRothera this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time

Answer (score 0):

You are using Date(date) where date acts as formatter which should not be the case.

Based on your db table's date column's format of date you have to use:

> date("Y/m/d") or
>   date("Y.m.d") or
>   date("Y-m-d")

***For eg.*** if the date in your table has format (Y/m/d) then your if statement should be:

```
if( $row['date'] == date(Y/m/d){
    echo "BOOKINGS TODAY";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use proper function for date in php. its date not DATE. recheck code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nextsession)) 
{
    if( date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['date'])) == date('Y-m-d')){
        echo "BOOKINGS TODAY";
    } else {
        echo "No Bookings";
    }
}
```