# Check current time is not between two time

Tags: php

I have two time like below in my php code

```
$fromTime = '20:00';
$toTime ='24:00';
```

Now I want get current time and want echo 1 if current time is not between this two time. I am not getting idea how I can do it, Let me know if someone can help me for do same.

Thanks!

Comment: `echo ($currentTimeStamp <= $toTimeStamp && $currentTimeStamp >= $fromTimeStamp) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: @MarkusZeller Aren't you comparing strings?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Pseudo Code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP compare time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time)

Comment: @MarkusZeller won't help OP anyway

Comment: He asked for an idea, and that's how it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function like this:

```
<?php

function isBetweenTime($fromTime, $toTime) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $now = date($format);

    $todayFromTime = date($format, strtotime(sprintf("%s %s:00", $today, $fromTime)));
    $todayToTime = date($format, strtotime(sprintf("%s %s:00", $today, $toTime)));

    if ($now >= $todayFromTime && $now <= $todayToTime) {
        return 'is between this time';
    } else {
        return '1';
    }
}

$fromTime = '20:00';
$toTime ='24:00';
echo isBetweenTime($fromTime, $toTime);

?>
```

**Explanation**

- set a default time zone so date/time is reasonable
- create today's date and find current time
- your from time only has hh:mm. Convert that to today's date/time
- do the same with to time
- now compare current time with your from/to times and make decisions

This gives you an idea how to start. There are other ways of approaching this solution as well.

Feel free to try https://rextester.com/CWBN43070 example online.