# How to compare this date and time 15 AUGUST at 8:00 PM IST ( GMT + 5:30) to current date and time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to compare this date and time

> `15 AUGUST at 8:00 PM IST ( GMT + 5:30)`

to current date and time in PHP
`15 AUGUST at 8:00 PM IST ( GMT + 5:30)` this date stored in db and need to compare with current time and if current time is 15 minutes less then need to fire my logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP compare time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time)

Comment: @MattHamer5 no mine one has 15 AUGUST at 8:00 PM IST ( GMT + 5:30) String

Comment: Does it have the year? August 15 of what year are you comparing against?

Comment: you can do directly at DB level, probably at PHP level as suggest by @MattHamer5 but without code is hard to say

Comment: @rovr138 no it doesnt have a year just need to compare with current month,it will always current month

Answer (score 1):

```
            $dateTime    = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
            $classDate   = explode(' ', '27 AUGUST at 8:00 PM IST ( GMT + 5:30)');
            $currentDate = explode(' ',date("d F")." at ".$dateTime->format("h:i A").' '.'IST ( GMT + 5:30)');
            
            if ($currentDate['0'] == $classDate['0']) {
                if ($currentDate['1'] == $classDate['1']) {
                    if ($currentDate['4'] == $classDate['4']) {
                        $minutes = (strtotime($classDate['3']) - strtotime($currentDate['3']))/60;
                        if ($minutes <= 15 && $minutes >= 0) {
                            echo "Your class is ready, Join now";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
Here i have exploded the dates and compared the date month as well compared time 
converting to `strtotime()` and boom.......
```